# AngularJS : Share data between controllers with service and restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, restangular

I'm new to angular and I'm still struggling with services, I have an application that queries the server for a survey, and shows the survey questions in a wizard, each question in the survey is in a route (/survey/:surveyId/question/:questionId)

What I'm trying to do is to load the survey the first time and then use that loaded data without querying it again.

As I understand I need a service, I'm using Restangular and I don't know what to return in my service, this is what I have:

```
angular.module('surveys')
    .factory('questionsService', ['Restangular', function (Restangular) {
        var surveyId = 1;

        return {
            questions: Restangular.one("survey", surveyId).getList("questions")
        }
}
```

and then in my controller I just do:

```
questionsService.questions.then(function (questions) {
            $scope.questions = questions;
            $scope.currentQuestion = $routeParams.page ? $scope.questions[$scope.currentQuestionIndex] : null;
        });
```

And this is working, I don't know if this is the correct way to do it.

But now I need other things in my service, like for example getting the unanswered questions, and that's where I'm lost, because if I put a function in getUnansweredQuestions() in my service I don't know how to get the questions, I don't know if they are already resolved.

I don't know if I'm clear enough, but I need some advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
surveys.run(function($rootScope,$http,$q) {
    function getData () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http(insertConfigObjectHere)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error (function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject();
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    $rootScope.myData = getData();
}
```

WARNING: I'm new to AngularJS too, but I think this might work, it's not tested too.